# Spring Data: 'neostore.nodestore.db' has a store version number that we cannot upgrade from

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm initialising a `GraphDatabaseService` with

```
String dbStr = "path\\to\\db";
GraphDatabaseService  dbs=  new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( dbStr );
```

And I get this error:

> 'neostore.nodestore.db' has a store version number that we cannot upgrade from. Expected 'v0.A.1' but file is version 'NodeStore v0.A.5'.

I believe the DB is generated by Neo4j 2.2.1

My dependencies are:

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <spring.data.version>3.3.1.RELEASE</spring.data.version>
</properties>


<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <spring.data.version>3.3.1.RELEASE</spring.data.version>
</properties>




<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Data Neo4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.data.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId> spring-data-neo4j-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.data.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId> spring-data-neo4j-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.data.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rest</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.data.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Can someone help shine some light on this compatibility issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've run the datastore with a more recent version of Neo4j. Neo4j does not support datastore downgrades. Between stable versions a upgrade path is well supported.

So either use a newer Neo4j version in your project. If that is not possible for whatever reason you can try to apply Michael's storeutils from https://github.com/jexp/store-utils/tree/revert-store. Be sure to use the revert-store branch. This tool copies over the database from one version to the other.

Comment: "Looks like you've run the datastore with a more recent version of Neo4j. " - More recent version than what?

Comment: ... a more recent version of Neo4j than the datastore. Maybe you've created the datastore with 2.2.3 but try to run the previously graph.db directory e.g. with Neo4j 2.0.x.